# Ominous red glow around blue notification bubble

Tags: bug, notifications, design, stack-exchange-button

On sites like those in Public beta where the red inbox bubble has a red glow to it, the blue notification has a *red* glow as well:

[image]

This clashes and sort of goes against the spirit of the notifications being less eye catching and more "quiet". Could they get a matching sky blue glow instead?

It should be noted that sites without the box-shadow/glow effect don't show the red shadow, so the notifications look significantly different, like the ones on Meta:

[image]

<sub><sup>Or did Sephiroth just call Meteor in my inbox?</sup></sub>

Comment: It's like a quiet little meteor bringing you untold doom and badges

Comment: I personally don't feel that the sky blue color is "notifying" enough. The red really stands out, but I oftentimes don't even notice that blue because it's so subtle. In fact, the red glow is the one thing that makes it stand out enough to be noticeable.

Comment: @animuson the subtlety is intentional, it's *not* urgent so it's *not* supposed to prompt the same level of attention.

Comment: Poor man's 3D effect. Like drawing with Paint. Oh, wait …

Answer (score 3):

I thought this was intentional.

And rather liked it.

If it changes now because of your calling attention to it, I'm going to send you *so many form letters...*

Comment: If it's intentional it's quite sloppy...sites like Meta have no "glow/shadow on the inbox bubble, so they now look quite different from notifications on sites that have the bubble...